# Swift collection view cell selected Image need to show full size on preview Imageview

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create bottom horizontal collection view photo gallery cell images by using `PhotoKit`. Here, if I select any collection view cell image I am showing it on preview Imageview (It is working now). Here, my problem is I set small size with .aspectFill for bottom horizontal collection view cell but preview Image I need to show full size, which means exact full photo without size limit. if I select it, Its showing very small size and blurry image on preview Imageview. The reason is I am using for thumbnail 120 height and width and assigning same image to preview imageview so now I can't able to see actual full size image which is in photo gallery. How to fix this?

Below Code I am using

```
// MARK: - Make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GalleryCollectionViewCell
        let asset = images[indexPath.row]
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        if cell.tag != 0 {
            manager.cancelImageRequest(PHImageRequestID(cell.tag))
        }
        cell.tag = Int(manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                            targetSize: CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 120.0),
                                            contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                            options: nil) { (result, _) in
                                                cell.picImage?.image = result
        })
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! GalleryCollectionViewCell
        previewImage.image = selectedCell.picImage.image //Here I am assigning cell Image to Preview Imageview

        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        self.collectionView.layoutSubviews()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You can use PHImageManager.default() and request image from assets. And checking images if it's stored in cloud could be a best practice ("isNetworkAccessAllowed = true") not to crash app. Sometimes a user stores all photos in cloud, because his/her device does not have enough storage.

Comment: I am using PhotoKit my question is If I click collection view cell image its showing very blurry image in preview Imageview. how to fix it? @erkutbas

Answer (score 0):

You have to request PhotoKit for image for apt or original size either by specifying size for your preview or using property of `PHImageManager.deafult().PHImageManagerMaximumSize`. Make sure contentMode is either default or apsectFit.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanagermaximumsize

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimage

Comment: I am using photoKit only. My question if I click collection view cell image. Its showing very blurry image in preview image. how to fix it? @Amber K

Comment: Good now read the first line of my answer again. You requested image for smaller size like your collection view cell hence will be blurry. Request for a bigger size or original size. Another wrong thing is you are requesting but keeping them in main memory hence your app memory usage will increase...

Answer (score 0):

For showing very blurry image in preview image, try to change image's content mode to aspect fit.That might solve the blurry image problem

Comment: Its already aspectfit. The problem is inside collection view cell image I am using targetSize: CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 120.0), also assigning same size image to preview image, So now I can't able to get good clarity full image because I am assigning thumbnail to preview. How to solve this @Shock

Comment: Please check if the image resolution, when assigning a image with less resolution to large image, you will get a blurry image